# does validation_data in model.fit() method in Tensorflow Keras have to be a tuple?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm implementing a complicated loss function so I use a custom layer to pass the loss. Something like：

```
class SIAMESE_LOSS(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SIAMESE_LOSS, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def mmd_loss(source_samples, target_samples):
        return mmd(source_samples, target_samples)

    @staticmethod
    def regression_loss(pred, labels):
        return K.mean(mae(pred, labels))

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        source_labels = inputs[0]
        target_labels = inputs[1]
        source_pred = inputs[2]
        target_pred = inputs[3]
        source_samples = inputs[4]
        target_samples = inputs[5]
        source_loss = self.regression_loss(source_pred, source_labels)
        target_loss = self.regression_loss(target_pred, target_labels)
        mmd_loss = self.mmd_loss(source_samples, target_samples)
        self.add_loss(source_loss)
        self.add_loss(target_loss)
        self.add_loss(mmd)
        self.add_metric(source_loss, aggregation='mean', name='source_mae')
        self.add_metric(target_loss, aggregation='mean', name='target_mae')
        self.add_metric(mmd_loss, aggregation='mean', name='MMD')
        return mmd_loss+target_loss+source_loss
```

So the labels are sent to the model as inputs.
Therefore fitting the model will be like:

```
        history = model.fit(
            x=[train_data_s, train_data_t, self.train_labels, self.train_data_t],
            y=None,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            epochs=base_epochs,
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=cp_callback,
            validation_data=[val_data_s, val_data_t, self.val_labels, self.val_labels_t],
            shuffle=True
        )
```

However, according to the official document in Tensorflow, validation_data should be:

> Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of
>   each epoch. The model will not be trained on this data.
>   validation_data will override validation_split. validation_data could
>   be: tuple (x_val, y_val) of Numpy arrays or tensors tuple (x_val,
>   y_val, val_sample_weights) of Numpy arrays dataset For the first two
>   cases, batch_size must be provided. For the last case,
>   validation_steps could be provided. Note that validation_data does not
>   support all the data types that are supported in x, eg, dict,
>   generator or keras.utils.Sequence.

There's no 'label' that should be passed since they're already handled by the model as inputs. How can I solve the problem if I still wanna use validation data?

Comment: did validation_data = (your_valid, None) raise u an error?

Comment: I tried and it actually worked. @MarcoCerliani

Answer (score 0):

to write your own loss you need to inherit from class Loss and then implement your loss calculation in the init and call methods.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss

so you dont need to train without passing y in model.fit()